# fast-import invalid argument

Tags: git, repository, git-bash, git-extensions

I am trying to migrate a Mercurial/Hg repository to git using fast-import.

I get a ways into the process when I run into this error:

> fatal: Unable to create
>   'c:/Users/micah_000/Desktop/git-gideon/.git/refs/tags/4.
>   0.6b_-->SFAS_4.0.3.lock': Invalid argument

I'm not sure how I can see what the original command was to see what was an invalid argument.

I am running on a Windows 8.1 system, but I am very Linux/bash savvy.

More diagnostics:

> ### Most Recent Commands Before Crash
>
> reset refs/tags/3.142.0.2   from :5376
>
> reset refs/tags/3.142.0.3   from :5385

...

> reset refs/tags/Test_Build_3.143.0.9   from :5610
>
> reset refs/tags/Test_Build_3.143.0.11   from :5622
>
> reset refs/tags/3.143.1   from :5634

Any suggestions?

Comment: Got a feeling there are characters (the arrow-y thing) in a past tag that are conflicting with git-bash or the file system. Not sure how to sanitize the names without breaking the way git/Hg relates tags to source/deltas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution: bring up TortoiseHG workbench and click on the magnifying glass icon.

Put this in the text box:

> tagged()

Then scroll through the check-ins below. The "tags" have little borders/boxes around then.

You can then r-click on the check ins with bad tags to add replacing/sanitized tag names (click "Add").

Then r-click on the same check in and type in the name of the still existing offending tag name for that check in. This should enable the "Remove" button. Remove it.

I wiped the destination git directory and re-ran the fast-import successfully.